# gflags full heap enabling with dlls doesn't work

Tags: c++, c, windows, debugging

I'm trying to enable full page heap with the dlls option using the debugging gflags tool. This to enable full page heap with an application but only with the specified dlls.

When I do not use the dlls option it work fine. I am able to get an exception on any attempt to write over an allocated memory block. But when I try to enable the same feature with the dlls option I do not get an exception on memory block allocated either by the main application code or the dll code when it should on the dll code according to the documentation.

I have tried on both Windows XP and Windows 7 and got the same behavior. I checked many times in case I would mistyped the dll name and couldn't enable the full page heap on the dll.

The tried both command to no avail :

```
gflags -p /enable test_dll1_app.exe /dlls test_dll1.dll

gflags -p /enable test_dll1_app.exe /dlls test_dll1.dll /full
```

This is the code I am using for testing:

**DLL code:**

```
#define TEST_DLL1_API __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" TEST_DLL1_API int * fntest_dll1(void)
{

   int * value0 = new int [413];
   int * value  = value0;

   for ( int i=0; i < 440; i++ )
      *value0++ = i;

   return value;
}
```

**Main application code :**

```
typedef int * (*AddFunc)();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   HINSTANCE LoadDll;
   LoadDll = LoadLibrary(_T("test_dll1.dll"));

   if ( LoadDll )
   {
      AddFunc pfnctFunc;
      pfnctFunc = (AddFunc)GetProcAddress(LoadDll, "fntest_dll1");
      if ( pfnctFunc )
      {
         int * value = pfnctFunc();

         for ( int i=0; i < 440; i++ )
            *value++ = i;
      }
   }

  int * value = new int [413];

  for ( int i=0; i < 440; i++ )
     *value++ = i;


  return 0;
```

}

Does anyone could help me pinpoint my mistake.
GB

Comment: I really don't see how this can work on a per dll basis. The only way to determine if a heap api was called by a particular module would be to perform a stack back trace on every call, which seems inordinately expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/dlls affects the DLL that calls the Win32 API HeapAlloc.  Since you allocate with new[] the DLL you need to specify is actually the C Runtime (e.g. msvcrt90.dll).

Comment: Yes! It works now! And since I own the DLL I was able to do a static link with the C Runtime thus enabling the full checking on the specific DLL not the msvcrt90.dll. MANY MANY Thanks !!!